# oracle form ''you cannot update this record''

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

I have a procedure in which I get values from different tables and calculate a certain decimal number. After that i try to post it on a `form text-field` which is a database item (update and insert allowed on the settings of block and item). everything works fine but the result wont show on the item and won't save in the database field. I get the error

> "you cannot update this record".

Can someone help? i have been working on it for two days now and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your user has update access on the table?
Check also if there are database triggers on the table that prevents you from updating the record.